# iOS - Differences over application main bundle path

Tags: ios, nsbundle

It's really easy to retrieve main bundle's path for an app:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath;
```

On a device running iOS 9, the result maybe something like:

> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/52E76B99-BF75-4E99-82BB-51307695E694/AppName.app

The  result shows that application installed via Xcode is stored under `/var/containers/Bundle/Application` on iOS 9.

But in some other devices, the main bundle's path is something like:

> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0E6DD32F-4E6F-4E54-B47E-A91060097E16/myapp.app

That's weird. That two paths differ a lot. I wonder what may produce that differences?

Answer (score 0):

You should never use the path if you're storing it for later use or comparison. As it will always change and generated run time by iOS but its iOS responsibility to get you the right path when you ask for the bundle path. So you should always use a path which is created run time.

[Good to read](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).

Comment: You are right. But the problem is, even if the main bundle path changed, they share the some parent directory (like `/var/containers/Bundle/Application`). While in my case, that paths is totally different (one start with `/private`, another dosen't).

Comment: When checks the path in device and simulator it will have this difference. Not sure why. But iOS decided.